# Macbook Air on Catalina freezes upon waking when connected to VPN

Tags: sleep-wake, performance, vpn

My Macbook Air freezes for like 30 seconds up to a minute if I have my VPN active and try to wake it up while it is trying to connect to the vpn. Seems like as soon as the connection is established the macbook is responding again. Tried to set a permanent DNS-server and turned off IPv6 but that didn‘t help to solve the problem. I also reseted SMC which also didn‘t help. The MBA wakes up with no stall at all if the vpn-connection was not active as it went to sleep. I‘m on Catalina 10.15.4 and running perfect-privacy-vpn.

Comment: Have you spoken to your VPN company about this?  It looks like a product support issue.

Comment: Well someone else posted a similar problem here so I guess it has nothing to do with my vpn-provider but with system behavior

Comment: If there's a similar problem posted, can you use the solution already provided?

Comment: Guess there is or was no solution for the problem found yet. I contacted the vpn-company and they just said that taking 30 seconds to connect seems to be fine, but didn‘t have any idea why the system is not responding during that period of time. I‘m still investigating on that problem. At the moment running plugged in the MBA seems to work fine.

Comment: Okay so I have turned on "Power Nap" now also when running on batterie. So far it seems to be working better I guess.

Comment: Nope ... did not work. Just had tried to wake it up after a longer time and it stalled again.